# NodeJS Bookshelf Users-Followers Relation Sample

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to create a Users-Followers Relationship with Bookshelf but I can't achieve it :(

Could you ilustrate me with a simple sample?

Thanks for your time :)

SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usersfollows;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
    "id" serial NOT NULL ,
    "username" varchar(40) NOT NULL ,
    "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    "pass" varchar(255)
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "users_username" ON users (username);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "users_email" ON users (email);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "users_hash" ON users (uuid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "users_uuid" ON users (uuid);
SELECT setval('users_id_seq', 18);

CREATE TABLE usersfollows (
    "id" serial NOT NULL ,
    "userId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    "followId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Comment: Can you describe the relationship (many-to-many, many-to-one)? Do you have the SQL for the tables you could show us (the relevant parts)? Any things in particular tripping you up?

Comment: @KalleBjörklid Updated with SQL I would like to define a BookshelfJS Model that enables me to make something like: `user.related('following')` and `user.related('followers')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
var User = Bookshelf.model.extend({
    tableName: 'user',
    follows: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(User, 'usersfollows', 'followId', 'userId');
    },
    followers: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(User, 'usersfollows', 'userId', 'followId');
    }
});
```

Note:

- I have not tested the above, nor have I done a similar case (many-to-many on a single table)
- Bookshelf.js documentation seems to implicitly state that it expects the connecting table (`usersfollows`) to have a composite PK rather than a separate one. If you cannot modify your table structure, you may need to use `through` - see [Bookshelf.js documentation for belongsToMany](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-belongsToMany).

If you can / need to try that composite PK thing, it should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usersfollows (
    "userId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    "followId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    PRIMARY KEY ("userId", "followId")
);
```

Anyhow, I'm not certan whether the above will work - I'm not too experienced with bookshelf myself - if it does not, let's hope somebody more knowledgeable comes along with a better answer.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my late response :S I will give a try when I have time, I've migrated the DB Schema to Knex migrations system and actually I'm using a custom function to get the data

Comment: About the composite Primary Key, it should work with my needs? I mean, if they are primary key i think they would be unique and I couldn't be able to add the same userId twice

Comment: The *combination* of `userId` and `followId` needs to be unique. So essentially you cannot follow a user twice (which I'd assume is what you want).

Comment: So the composite PK sets unique only to the combination of the fields, that looks awesome :O I'm so noob in PostgreSQL...

Comment: I tried with composite PK and works like a charm with your snippet. Thanks for all! Now I'm wondering how to recover the data in the relation table (eg. status of the relationship)